# Bootstrap tooltip on Select option not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I need a tooltip to be displayed for each options in the select box

```
 <select ng-model="rightList" class="form-control" size="13" multiple>
            <option 
                ng-repeat="item in selectedList" 
                value="{{$index}}" 
                uib-tooltip="See? Now click away..."
                tooltip-placement="right">
                {{item.name}}
            </option>
  </select>
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

***JS (Data in Controller):***

```
$scope.selectedList = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'name1',
      toolTip:'tooltip one'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'name2',
      toolTip:'tooltip two'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'name3',
      toolTip:'tooltip three'
    }];
```

***HTML:***

```
<select>
 <option  
     data-toggle="tooltip" 
     data-placement="right" 
     title="{{item.toolTip}}" 
     ng-repeat="item in selectedList" 
     value="{{$index}}"> 
     {{item.name}}
 </option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Keep the tooltip value in title.
EX:

```
<select size="5" ng-model="displayTags">
<option  ng-repeat="tag in tags | filter:searchTags">
<span title="tag.tagName">{{tag.tagName}}</span>    </option>
</select>
```